# Why does this code not throw a NullPointerException?

Tags: java, multithreading, nullpointerexception, thread-safety

## Background

I would like to understand why a snippet of code does ***not*** throw a NullPointerException.

## Source Code

Consider the following code:

```
public class Agent {
  public List files = new ArrayList();

  public void deliver() {
    if( files != null && files.iterator().hasNext() ) {
      File file = (File)files.iterator().next();
    }

    files = new ArrayList();
  }
}
```

The `deliver` method is called repeatedly, whilst the following code runs in a separate thread:

```
  public void run() {
    agent.files = null;
  }
```

There is only a single `agent` instance.

## Problem

A NullPointerException is never thrown.

However, when the `deliver` method pauses, even for 0 milliseconds, a NullPointerException is thrown as expected:

```
  public void deliver() {
    if( files != null ) {
      Thread.currentThread().sleep( 0 );

      if( files.iterator().hasNext() ) {
        File file = (File)files.iterator().next();
      }
    }

    files = new ArrayList();
  }
```

My understanding was that there is, in theory, a race condition between checking for `files == null` and calling `files.iterator().hasNext()`. In practice, I cannot trigger the race condition without introducing the pause (i.e., splitting the null check from the subsequent method call).

## Question

Why does the first `deliver` method not throw an exception when the null check and usage are combined in the same statement?

Comment: Can you post `javap` output where appropriate surrounding race condition areas?

Comment: What happens when you make `files` `volatile`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Two things:

1. Thread.sleep(0) still halts execution (potentially more than 0 milliseconds).  Basically, even a 0 sleep causes execution on that thread to halt briefly, and then restart.  This gives the other thread a chance to run and finish, which is why you're able to trigger the race condition.
2. files should be `volatile`, otherwise the JVM is permitted to optimize in such a way that you may never notice that it's changing value, because it doesn't think it needs to maintain consistency between the threads.

Comment: Does this mean that the JVM can treat the null check and the subsequent usage as an atomic operation, unless explicitly set to `volatile`?

Comment: A thread can have a local copy of variables like files in your case. Therefore setting files to something else outside that thread will have no effect on the local variable. The thread will eventually check for outside modifications, but in your case probably at a point where files is always set to a value. Volatile will make sure that the Thread _always_ checks for outside modifications. So: no, it will not treat this as an atomic operation, you just got lucky in your example on your machine in your JVM.